# Форма уходит за границы экрана

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем доброго времени суток.Столкнулся с такой проблемой:при изменения размера формы она уходит за границы экрана(Левая и нижняя граница).Так вот как можно проконтролировать это и если форма выйдет за левую границу то сдвинуть ее вправо а если формы выйдет за нижнюю границу то сдвинуть ее вверх.Для более подробного описания проблемы можете посмотреть видео: [Нажмите сюда](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHNi0RsjTvU&feature=youtu.be&hd=1)

Comment: Как быть в ситуации, когда форма больше экрана?

Comment: Не совсем.На видео видно что форму можно сдвинуть налево когда он переходит правую границу.Вот как можно это проконтролировать?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea` чтобы определить размеры экрана.

В подписчике не событие `Form_Resize` напишите:

```
if (Right > Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width)
    Left = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Width;
```

Comment: То есть если if( Left+Width>Screen.PrimareScreen.WorkingArea.Width) ....change location....?Правильно понимаю?

Comment: Примерно так. Вы пробовали?

Comment: Я так пробовал  var sc = Screen.GetBounds(this);
            if (this.Right > sc.Width)
            {
                Rectangle r = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea;
                this.Location= new Point(this.Right - sc.Width,this.Location.Y);
            }

Comment: Но при этом форма ужасно лагает.

Comment: Должно выглядеть примерно так http://youtu.be/M8n-DRmZLqk?hd=1

Comment: Обновил ответ...

Comment: Не работает http://youtu.be/JpygcoY_5uY?hd=1

Comment: Ну по видео видно, что ваша форма следует за курсором, приведите весь код, в котором меняются габариты или положение окна

Comment: Перенесите эти две строчки после присваивания `t.Location` в обработчике `MouseMove` (не забудьте дописать t.Right, t.Left и т.д.)

Comment: http://youtu.be/3iBUK71tp9A?hd=1